# Changing UTC /GMT in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, time

```
Select dtCreated, fTotal, txtOrderStatus, txtOrderRef, txtPaymentMethod 
from  order1 
where  txtOrderStatus != ('incomplete')  
AND year(dtCreated)=2015 order by  dtCreated ASC ;
```

I am required to also change the timezone to GMT +8, how do i do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(yourTime,'+00:00','+08:00');
```

Refer the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz):

> CONVERT_TZ() converts a datetime value dt from the time zone given by
>   from_tz to the time zone given by to_tz and returns the resulting
>   value. Time zones are specified as described in Section 10.6, “MySQL
>   Server Time Zone Support”. This function returns NULL if the arguments
>   are invalid.

Comment: how do i encorporate it into my statement

Comment: @nooralhabbal:- Is `dtCreated` the column which you want to convert?

Comment: its a column that contains the date, i want to filter out only the dates in the year 2015 and change time zone to +8